# How to manually stop or start the @InboundChannelAdapter by ourself?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Helo Everyone,

i am working on spring cloud data flow

i created the application and it is working fine but we have one requirement like it will be able to start/stop whenever we need..

if i keep autoStartup="false" it is not starting at first,but i dont know how to start or stop after that.

Most of the places having only xml config.

Tried some code with some online articles but it didn't work.

can anyone know how to resolve this and if is there any example means it will be really helpful.

Actually if autoStartup is false and using CommandLineRunner i can able to start the service.but the same thing if i tried with rest endpointit is throwing error.

Below is the code snippet.

below snippet is from my code.

```
package com.javatechie.service;

import com.javatechie.impl.ProductBuilder;
import com.javatechie.TbeSource;
import com.javatechie.model.Product;
import com.javatechie.stopping.StopPollingAdvice;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.EndpointId;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.config.ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@Component
@EnableIntegration
@RestController
public class ProcessingCl {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ac;


    @Bean
    @Scope("singleton")
    private ProductBuilder dataAccess() {
        return new ProductBuilder();
    }


    @Bean
    @EndpointId("inboundtest")
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = TbeSource.PR1, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "100", errorChannel = "errorchannel"),autoStartup = "false")
    public Supplier<Product> getProductSource(ProductBuilder dataAccess) 
     {
     return ()->dataAccesss.getNext();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageChannel controlChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "controlChannel")
    ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus() {
        ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean expressionControlBusFactoryBean = new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
        return expressionControlBusFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(@Qualifier("controlChannel") MessageChannel controlChannel) {
        return (String[] args) -> {
            System.out.println("Starting incoming file adapter: ");
            boolean sent = controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@inboundtest.start()"));
            System.out.println("Sent control message successfully? " + sent);
            while (System.in.available() == 0) {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
        };
    }

    @GetMapping("/stop11")
    void test() {
        controlChannel().send(new GenericMessage<>("@inboundtest.stop()"));
        System.out.println("it is in call method to stop");
    }


    @GetMapping("/start11")
    void test1() {
        controlChannel().send(new GenericMessage<>("@inboundtest.start()"));
        System.out.println("it is in call method to start");
    }
  

}
```

Following is the error message.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'unknown.channel.name'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=@inboundtest.start(), headers={id=82c74865-2f68-c192-7d48-501bf3b28e02, timestamp=1608643036650}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=@inboundtest.start(), headers={id=82c74865-2f68-c192-7d48-501bf3b28e02, timestamp=1608643036650}]] with root cause

org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

Answer (score 0):

The control bus, `@EndpointId` and command as `@inboundtest.start()` is the way to go.

Only the problem that you don't show what is a subscriber for that `TbeSource.PR1` channel.
That's probably where you are missing the point of Spring Integration: you start producing messages from that polling channel adapter, but there is no something like service activator having that `TbeSource.PR1` channel as input.

I see you say it is Data Flow, but it is not clear from your description and configuration where is the binding for a `TbeSource.PR1` destination. Do you have something like `@EnableBinding` and respective `Source` definition?